# Operand type clash: time is incompatible with float for compute

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the below query which errors out as Operand type clash: time is incompatible with float

```
select (sum(ReceivedContacts) * CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(s, SUM(( DATEPART(hh, AverageWaitTime) * 3600 ) + ( DATEPART(mi, AverageWaitTime) * 60 ) + DATEPART(ss, AverageWaitTime)), 0)) / Sum(ReceivedContacts)) AS total_time
from TelephonyStats
```

Data Type for Received Contacts is float and AverageWaitTime is time

Please help

Comment: You have already answered your question. You are multiplying float on time.

Comment: Conversion from `time` to `float` is not allowed. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I am try to use SUMPRODUCT formula is excel in sql. I want to calculate total avg wait time

Comment: @Rajiv Total average waiting time? Would it be the average of all values in the `AverageWaitTime` column?

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `CONVERT` to `TIME` and tidy up the rest of parentheses and it should work. Try the below query:

```
SELECT 
        SUM(ReceivedContacts) * ( 
           SUM ( 
                  ( DATEPART(hh, AverageWaitTime) * 3600 ) + 
                  ( DATEPART(mi, AverageWaitTime) * 60 ) + 
                  ( DATEPART(ss, AverageWaitTime) )
               ) / SUM(ReceivedContacts)
        ) AS total_time
FROM TelephonyStats
```

Comment: Thanks, I would like to convert the value back to time as, per excel I am using SUMPRODUCT and divide it by TotalReceivedContacts. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't divide a number by a time value. It doesn't make any sense. I have a feeling you're actually trying to get a different output, but this is not the correct way.

Comment: Basically I am trying to calculate weighted average. In excel I am able to get the value based on hh:mm:ss.

Comment: @Rajiv What does your Excel formula look like?

Comment: =+SUMPRODUCT(E2:E17,G2:G17)/E19

Comment: Column E contains numbers and Column G contains time in hh:mm:ss format.